# Win32 console problem

Tags: winapi, console, native

is it possible to create a program that works as console application if started from the console and works as windows program (with GUI) when started otherwise?

If it is possible - how can I do that?

regards
Tobias

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need the program to act as a console application (e.g. print the usage information to the console) you must complile as a console application. A windows application will not have access to the console and cmd.exe will not wait for it to finish before printing the prompt and accepting the next command.

The best solution is to have two versions, one for command line and one for the GUI (which users usually run via a link on the desktop or start menu).

If you insist on using a single binary you will have to live with a console window appearing, at least for a short time.   You can get rid of the console window using

```
FreeConsole();
```

You can tell that your application was run from GUI if it is the only process attached to the console.  You can use `GetConsoleProcessList` to find the list of processes attached to the console.

Answer (score 4):

If you set the program up to build as a GUI program you can then attempt to attach to the console using [AttachConsole()](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms681952%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). You you attach OK then you were started from a console and you can proceed to redirect your standard handles to the newly attached console.

In this way you can start up and see if you are being started from a console that you can attach to and if so become a console program. If you cant attach you can show a GUI.

I've had some success with this, the main problem I have is redisplaying the command window's prompt when my program exits (which is how normal console programs operate), but I expect you could do something clever (read the console buffer on start up and find the prompt to redisplay when you exit?) if you really wanted to ...

Comment: But wont that create a new console window rather than connecting you to the command prompt that launched you's console window?

Comment: Yes. There's no documented restriction on calling `AttachConsole` from a GUI program; it's just not the default.

Answer (score 3):

This is the answer from Dan Tillett and it is remarkably effective.  No flashes, no .com and .exe to trick cmd.exe.  Seems to work flawlessly typing the command, in a .bat file, with focus, without focus and as double-click GUI app.

It's the bees knees!

Here is web page describing it, but I've posted it here because if that page goes 404 next month or 2 years from now, the excellent and "most complete" solution I've seen would be "off the grid".

http://www.tillett.info/2013/05/13/how-to-create-a-windows-program-that-works-as-both-as-a-gui-and-console-application/

```
#define WINVER 0x0501 // Allow use of features specific to Windows XP or later.
#define _WIN32_WINNT 0x0501
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>
#include <io.h>
#include <fcntl.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#pragma comment(lib, "User32.lib")

// Attach output of application to parent console
static BOOL attachOutputToConsole(void) {
HANDLE consoleHandleOut, consoleHandleError;
int fdOut, fdError;
FILE *fpOut, *fpError;

if (AttachConsole(ATTACH_PARENT_PROCESS)) {
    //redirect unbuffered STDOUT to the console
    consoleHandleOut = GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE);
    fdOut = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)consoleHandleOut, _O_TEXT);
    fpOut = _fdopen(fdOut, "w" );
   *stdout = *fpOut;
    setvbuf(stdout, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    //redirect unbuffered STDERR to the console
    consoleHandleError = GetStdHandle(STD_ERROR_HANDLE);
    fdError = _open_osfhandle((intptr_t)consoleHandleError, _O_TEXT);
    fpError = _fdopen(fdError, "w" );
    *stderr = *fpError;
    setvbuf(stderr, NULL, _IONBF, 0 );

    return TRUE;
    }
//Not a console application
return FALSE;
}

//Send the "enter" to the console to release the command prompt on the parent console
static void sendEnterKey(void) {
INPUT ip;
// Set up a generic keyboard event.
ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
ip.ki.time = 0;
ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

//Send the "Enter" key
ip.ki.wVk = 0x0D; // virtual-key code for the "Enter" key
ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

// Release the "Enter" key
ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
}

int WINAPI WinMain(HINSTANCE hInstance, HINSTANCE hPrevInstance, PSTR lpCmdLine, INT nCmdShow) {
int argc = __argc;
char **argv = __argv;
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(hPrevInstance);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(lpCmdLine);
UNREFERENCED_PARAMETER(nCmdShow);
BOOL console;
int i;

//Is the program running as console or GUI application
console = attachOutputToConsole();

if (console) {
    //Print to stdout
    printf("Program running as console application\n");
    for (i = 0; i < argc; i++) {
         printf("argv[%d] %s\n", i, argv[i]);
         }

    //Print to stderr
    fprintf(stderr, "Output to stderr\n");
    }
else {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Program running as windows gui application",
    "Windows GUI Application", MB_OK | MB_SETFOREGROUND);
}

//Send "enter" to release application from the console
//This is a hack, but if not used the console doesn't know the application has returned
//"enter" only sent if the console window is in focus
if (console && GetConsoleWindow() == GetForegroundWindow()){
    sendEnterKey();
    }
return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The program itself will never know how it was started. Unless you are willing to pass an execution arguments to the program. For example: program.exe -GUI ... you can capture the passed parameters and decide how the program should run based on parameters passed.

your program whould be something like:

```
class MainClass 
{
   public static int Main(string[] args) 
   {
      // Test if input arguments were supplied:
      if(args[0]=="GUI") 
          new myGUI().show(); //runs an instance of your gui
      else
          //you know what should go here
   }
}
```

Comment: one can check the parent process for the command shell to determine whether it was started via cmd or otherwise. The main problem is the cmd window that is shown if the flag is set in the pe header.

Comment: You can hide the cmd window. It's possible.

Comment: you can check for std handle with GetStartUpInfo. (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683230(v=vs.85).aspx) plus Len's Holgate great idea. so you are wrong, there are ways.

Answer (score 0):

You can sort of guess whether you are started from the console or not by doing this:

```
CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE), &csbi);
fConsole = csbi.dwCursorPosition.X | csbi.dwCursorPosition.Y;
```

It's a guess -- if your cursor position is not 0,0 than you are in a console and can work as a console app.  Otherwise go and create your windows.

Another way to guess is to look at the process tree and see what process launched your app.  If it is cmd.exe go in console mode, otherwise go into GUI mode.

Answer (score 0):

Make it a console application and put this into the code:

```
void ConsoleWindowVisible(bool show)
{
    DWORD dummy;
    if
    (
        !show && // Trying to hide
        GetConsoleProcessList(&dummy, 1) == 1 // Have our own console window
    )
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow, SW_HIDE); // Hide the window
    else // Trying to show or use parent console window
        ShowWindow(GetConsoleWindow, SW_NORMAL); // Show the window
}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    ConsoleWindowVisible(false);
}
```

Cheers.

gor.f.gyolchanyan@gmail.com